# Get max value from list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a grid view, I am sending ID and some bid value on click of submit to some list.

Now I want to pick max value from that list against each ID.

Comment: How are you going to do this? using C#? or OOTB?

Comment: I am using c# @ Malin De Silva

Comment: Ok check the answer

Comment: You have tagged the question with SharePoint online, and then say you use C#. Are you doing this in a provider hosted app? Please feel free to edit your answer to add more details, it is not easy to grasp what you are doing right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question looks a bit confusing as you have not mentioned the way you need to get the Maximum value. But since you have mentioned, you have a grid view, I am assuming you need to show the maximum values in a ASP.net gridview.

```
public SPListItemCollection GetMaxValueList()
    {
        using (SPSite objSite = new SPSite(sSiteUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb objWeb = objSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList objList = objWeb.Lists[sListName];

                SPQuery objQuery = new SPQuery();
                objQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='RefId' /><FieldRef Name='Bid' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
                objQuery.Folder = objList.RootFolder;

                // Execute the query against the list
                SPListItemCollection colItems = objList.GetItems(objQuery);
                SPListItemCollection maxValues = new SPListItemCollection();
                if (colItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    int previousId = 0;
                    foreach (SPListItem listItem in colItems)
                    {
                        int currentId = int.Parse(listItem["RefId"].toString());
                        if (currentId != previousId)
                        {
                            maxValues.Add(listItem);
                        }
                        previousId = currentId;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return maxValues;
    }
```

This method will return only the Max values.I have assumed the id column name is RefId and it is an integer value here.